How to see console output from Minimal API when debugging in IDE
With Azure Functions, when I run in the IDE it brings up a console. With a Minimal API project it does not do this, however I can run it with "dotnet watch" from a terminal and see the console output... but then the debugger isn't attached.
How do I combine these two so the experience is more like debugging an Azure function where, when I hit play, I have a place to see messages logged to the console?

You could try the following steps to show Integrated Terminal to replace the terminal and you could attach the debugger and see the output from the Integrated Terminal at the same time.

Open Visual Studio
Select Tools Menu
Then Options Selection
Focus Projects and Solutions
And then ASP.NET Core
Next to Run web server in
Choose Integrated Terminal
Click OK

Based on my test, I could see the console output from the Integrated Terminal.(I tested it in asp.net core web api, but it should be the same as azure function API)

